# Retrieve data from PHP via Ajax / jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need help with my code, how can I get the value bar into the .table (for example . thx

**My php file foo.php**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar'));

?>
```

**My jQuery code**

```
$(function () {

    $('button#click').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: 'foo.php',
            data: {data.foo},
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function (data) { $('.table').html("<p>"+data.foo+"</p>"); }

        });

    });

});
```

Comment: how your data look like ?

Comment: what is data in  `data: data,` ?

Comment: check you console for error. Is your ajax success callback fired or not?

Comment: I need data from array in php file, ex. bar

Comment: you have error on this line "data: data,"  here data is undefined variable in this case you are not passing any value so replace that line with this "data: {},"

Comment: How pass data like a POST array? in data{}

Comment: like data: {data: 'mydata'}

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { vandenberg.humlak.cz/:64
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: remove `header();` from your php it already is being encoded in json and you are expecting json from php, secondly as @tushar said data:data needs to be fixed third you have many things calling data so use your identifiers carefully...

Comment: I removed header() but still error event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. I use 1.10.2 jquery

Comment: Try `JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: See this code, I try upload complete code

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('button#click').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'foo.php',
            data: {},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('.table').html("<p>" + data.foo + "</p>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use it another way

```
    $(function () {
    $('button#click').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'foo.php',
            data: 'key1=val1&key2=val2',
            success: function (data) {
                result = eval('(' +data + ')')
                $('.table').html("<p>" + result.foo + "</p>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And php file :

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar'));
?>
```